# how to update the TyphoonConfig at runtime

Tags: typhoon

I am creating the factory inside the testcase

```
        + (TyphoonComponentFactory*)integrationTestFactory
{
    static TyphoonComponentFactory* factory;
    static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
    dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^
    {
        factory = [[TyphoonBlockComponentFactory alloc] initWithAssemblies:@[
            [MainAssembly assembly],
            [Kernel assembly],
            [NetworkComponents assembly],
            [PersistenceComponents assembly]
        ]];

        //Other config here. . . 
        TyphoonConfigPostProcessor *configurer = [TyphoonConfigPostProcessor configurer];
        [configurer useResourceWithName:@"testConfig.properties"];
        [factory attachPostProcessor:configurer];
        //this may be necessary
        [factory makeDefault 

    });
    return factory;
}
```

### Then accessing it

```
  - (void)setUp
{
    [super setUp];

    factory_instance = [LoginTest integrationTestFactory];
}
```

Finally accessing the assembly gives the error value for config key is not configured

```
DAO *dataManager = [(DaoAssembly*)factory_instance DAO];
```

Assembly is as follows

-(id)DAO
{

```
return [TyphoonDefinition withClass:[DAO class] configuration:^(TyphoonDefinition* definition)
        {
            [definition useInitializer:@selector(shareManager)];
            [definition injectProperty:@selector(apikey) with:TyphoonConfig(@"api.key")];
            [definition injectProperty:@selector(dataParser) with:[self dataParser]];
            definition.scope = TyphoonScopeSingleton;

        }];
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not able to reproduce what you're experiencing, as verified with the following test case.

Please try this simple example for yourself - perhaps it will shed some light on what the problem is.

**SomeProperties.properties:**

```
damsels.rescued=12
```

**Knight.h/.m:**

```
@interface Knight : NSObject

@property(nonatomic) NSUInteger damselsRescued;

@end
```

**MyAssembly.m:**

```
- (id)knight
{
    return [TyphoonDefinition withClass:[Knight class] configuration:
        ^(TyphoonDefinition *definition) {
        [definition injectProperty:@selector(damselsRescued)
             with:TyphoonConfig(@"damsels.rescued")];        
    }];
}
```

**IntegrationTests.m:**

```
@interface IntegrationTests : XCTestCase
{
    TyphoonComponentFactory *_factory;
}


@end

@implementation IntegrationTests

+ (TyphoonComponentFactory *)integrationTestFactory
{
    static TyphoonComponentFactory *factory;
    static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
    dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
        factory = [[TyphoonBlockComponentFactory alloc] initWithAssemblies:@[
            [MyAssembly assembly],
        ]];

        //Other config here. . .
        TyphoonConfigPostProcessor *configurer = [TyphoonConfigPostProcessor configurer];
        [configurer useResourceWithName:@"SomeProperties.properties"];
        [configurer useResourceWithName:@"SomeOtherProperties.properties"];
        [factory attachPostProcessor:configurer];
        [factory makeDefault];
    });
    return factory;
}


- (void)setUp
{
    _factory = [IntegrationTests integrationTestFactory];
}

- (void)testPropertiesAreSet
{
    Knight *knight = [(InfrastructureComponentsAssembly *) _factory knight];
    XCTAssertEqual(knight.damselsRescued, 12);
}

@end
```

Comment: issue resolved,,error was coming due to how  pod file was set up with typhoon added to both main and test target.